# Magento 2 : Call to a member function getCustomerIsGuest() on null error

Tags: magento2

Call to a member function getCustomerIsGuest() on null at

```
/vendor/GuestStoreCredit/Model/Balance.php

   protected function _ensureCustomer()
    {
        try {
            if ($this->state->getAreaCode() != \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND && $this->helper->canConvertGuest()) {
                if ($this->getOrder()->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
                    $customer = $this->helper->createNewCustomerFromOrder($this->getOrder());
                    if ($customer) {
                        $this->setCustomer($this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customer->getId()));
                        $this->helper->sendStoreCreditEmail($customer);
                    } elseif ($this->getOrder()) {
                        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
                        $customer  = $this->_customerFactory->create();
                        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                        $customer->loadByEmail($this->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())->getId();
                        if ($customer->getId()) {
                            $this->setCustomer($this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customer->getId()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Error creating new customer for store credit.");
        }
        if ($this->getCustomer() && $this->getCustomer()->getId()) {
            $this->setCustomerId($this->getCustomer()->getId());
        }
        if (!$this->getCustomerId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please specify a customer ID.'));
        }
        if (!$this->getCustomer()) {
            $this->setCustomer($this->_customerFactory->create()->load($this->getCustomerId()));
        }
        if (!$this->getCustomer()->getId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Please specify a valid customer.')
            );
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts how to solve this error ?

Comment: any thoughts on this please ?

Comment: getOrder() returns null. What does the getOrder() method do?

Comment: That returns order object.

Comment: In this case it doesn't though. The error message reads "Call to a member function getCustomerIsGuest() on null" which means that the getOrder() method returned null and not an order object. To solve the issue you'll have to look into why getOrder() doesn't return an order object as you expect.

Comment: yes, thankyou very much for the advice, i am checking it.

Comment: public function getOrder()
    {
        if (!$this->_order instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order) {
            $this->_order = $this->getOrderId() ?
                $this->orderRepository->get($this->getOrderId()) :
                $this->_orderFactory->create();
        }

        return $this->_order->setHistoryEntityName($this->entityType);
    }

Comment: Hello, this is method which is called & returns null for order object.